# android java disable touch screen home button

Tags: java, android, android-theme

im creating apps with slider on the first run, but seems, android home button covers my layout.
[image]

how can i hide touch screen home button?

thanks

i try use this code but not working :

```
 getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

i try use padding bottom but its show some space on device that not use touch screen home button.

any body experience this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to hide the navigation bar

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: Android immersive mode will work perfect.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

[immersive mode android click here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public static int getSoftButtonsBarSizePort(Activity activity) {
        // getRealMetrics is only available with API 17 and +
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int usableHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
            int realHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
            if (realHeight > usableHeight)
                return ((realHeight - (usableHeight)) / 4);
            else
                return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

and in on create, you have to

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) layout2.getLayoutParams();
    relativeParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, getSoftButtonsBarSizePort(DimgloActivity.this));  // left, top, right, bottom
    layout2.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this method in onCreate before setting view like this:-

```
    Constants.fullScreen(this); //call before setting view
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_generator);
    final_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.final_tv);
    .
    .
```

And create this function in your Constant, you can comment or remove some lines according to your need

```
public static void fullScreen(Activity activity) 
{
   activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```